# How to call to an API endpoint in controller in from a middleware in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I want to call to an API in my app to reset the access token after the access token is expired from a middleware in NestJS. Here is my middleware file. I got stuck at the step of API calling to the localhost endpoint /reset (This API link is an API endpoint of my NestJS app btw)

```js
    import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
    import { AuthUtilService } from 'src/shared/utils/auth-util/auth-utils.service';
    import { EnvironmentConfigService } from 'src/infrastructure/config/environment/environment/environment.service';
    import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
    @Injectable()
    export class ResetTokenMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
       constructor(
          private readonly authUtil: AuthUtilService,
          private readonly config: EnvironmentConfigService,
          private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
       }
       async use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
          const { access_token, refresh_token } = request.cookies
          const decodedToken = this.authUtil.getDecodedToken(access_token, this.config.getJwtSecret())
          const decodedRefreshToken = this.authUtil.getDecodedToken(refresh_token, this.config.getRefreshSecret())
          if (decodedRefreshToken !== null) {
             if (decodedToken === null) {
                console.log(decodedToken)
                let data = await this.httpService.post('http://localhost:8080/hand-market-api/auth/reset').toPromise()
                console.log(data)
                return next()
             } else {
                return next()
             }
          } else {
             return response.status(401).json({ message: 'Login session has expired' });
          }
    
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why call the endpoint with a new HTTP request? Why not just call the service that endpoint is attached to directly?